# catopen() does not set errno when it fails in some cases

Tags: c, solaris, opensolaris

catopen is failing to open same cat file in different servers, with same setup.

When errno is 0 it means no error from my understanding.

Please tell me if anyone has seen like this before.
If any one knows the reason why it is happening it will be very helpful for me

Sample code i wrote

```
int main()
{

   nl_catd cat;

   string fileName;

   cout<<"Enter the cat file name: ";

   cin>>fileName;

   cat = catopen(fileName.c_str(), 0);

   if (cat == (nl_catd)-1)

   {

      cerr << "Unable to open catalogue: " << fileName <<" ....and the Error number: "<<errno<<"\n";

      exit(1);

   }

   printf("File opened...\n");

   catclose( cat );

   exit(0);

}
```

Output for above code

### For successful case:

```
./a.out

Enter the cat file name: LinkMonitor.epod.cat

File opened...
```

### For faliure case:

```
./a.out

Enter the cat file name: ehap_ac_in.epod.cat

Unable to open catalogue: ehap_ac_in.epod.cat0
```

---

Here 0 is the error code.

Comment: Is the problem only with one filename, or with many? If it's only with one file, maybe it's corrupt?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cleared `errno` when you wrote the string `"Unable to open catalogue: "` to `cerr`.

You have to save the value of `errno` straight away.

```
cat = catopen(fileName.c_str(), 0); 

if (cat == (nl_catd)-1) 

{ 
   int errno_catopen = errno;
   cerr << "Unable to open catalogue: " << fileName <<" ....and the Error number: "<<errno_catopen <<"\n";
   exit(errno_catopen);
}
```

Comment: This might be the issue, but errno is not supposed to be reset by successful calls, only set by failing ones.

Comment: Posix functions and C std library functions are not any more supposed to set `errno` to zero. The rule only applies to C not C++ inc. iostreams or fstreams. And you still cannot assume that of any other function, including `cerr.operator<<()`. Who knows what setup has to happen the first time you write to `cerr`?